# Elasticsearch phrase prefix results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two ES queries:

```
{match:{text:{query: "text box", type: "phrase"}}}
{match:{text:{query: "text bo", type: "phrase_prefix"}}}
```

The problem is that the second query returns fewer documents than the first one, although I would expect the second query to return all records from the first one plus something extra. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `text` field `not_analyzed` or analyzed with something similar to `keyword`?

Comment: We're using standard built-in analyzer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to `max_expansions` being set to its default value 10

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "text": {
        "query": "text bo",
        "max_expansions": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This [thread](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-exactly-works-quot-max-expansions-quot-in-match-phrase-prefix-query-td4030146.html) will help you understand how terms are expanded. make `max_expansions` 1000 and see the results.

Basically you have lot of words starting with bo like *bond, boss* and since *'x'* comes last alphabetically, you are not getting what you expect.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks a lot!